# Return comma delimited string with just the values

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-class

I have the following code that almost works perfectly but it returns a comma delimited string of the name value pairs as below.

```
{ stringName = Fred },
{ stringName = Monkey Bars },
{ stringName = Eagles }
```

What I want is a comma delimited string of just the values.

```
Fred, Monkey Bars, Eagles
```

And my code

```
var liftsOpens =
    (from li in db.Lifts
    where li.LiftStatusMorning == "Open"
    select new {li.LiftName}).ToList();

var lom = string.Join(",", liftsOpens);
```

I've tried **liftsOpens.LiftName** but I get errors, do I have to use **Replace** or is there an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Linq-statement, you are selecting a list of anonymous objects that have a property which contain the value that you need. So you are passing a list of your anonymous objects to `string.Join()` 
But I think you want an enumeration of these **strings** (no need for anonymous objects here)...

Sou you could try `select li.LiftName` instead of `select new {li.LiftName}`.

And if you use **.NET <4.0**, you need to call `.ToArray()` instead of `.ToList()` to make `string.Join()` work properly (see MSDN: [.NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) / [.NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

```
var liftsOpens =
     (from li in db.Lifts
      where li.LiftStatusMorning == "Open"
      select li.LiftName)  // <<== Select the string
    .ToArray();            // <<== If .NET prior to 4.0

var lom = string.Join(",", liftsOpens);
```